# How would I check If a role has a certain word in it discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have this code so far which does not work.

`if (member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name.includes === 'Gang‏‏‎ ‎'))`

basically I have like 9 different roles that all have the word gang in them and instead of checking if a user has each role individually I want to check if they have any of the roles all at once. since it will save space and be less of a headache. is there any way to do this effectively? I'm open to all answers, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `includes` method is defined on the string prototype and takes the search string as argument (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

While your current code compares that method to the string literal `'Gang '` you instead want to provide the search string as an argument like this: `role.name.includes('Gang‏‏‎ ‎')`

Comment: one more question if you don't mind, how could I rephrase this if statement into a roles.remove statement I've tried this so far: 

```const gangs = message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name.includes('Gang‏‏‎ ‎'))


message.member.roles.remove(gangs)```